# How to get a list after a word and before a character

Tags: python

I currently have this string and I would like to extract the names out, for example, Garet Hayes, Ronald Allen, etc.

```
Executives
Garet Hayes - Director, Public Relations
Ronald Allen - Chief Executive Officer
Gilbert Danielson - Executive Vice President and Chief Financial Officer
Steven Michaels - President
John Robinson - Executive Vice President and President and Chief Executive Officer, Progressive Finance Holdings LLC
```

I am able to extract the first name, Garet Hayes, by this code:

```
def partiesExtractor(doc):
    executives = []
    executives.append(doc[doc.lower().index('executives') + len('executives') + 1 : doc.index(' -')])
    return executives
```

But I feel like there should be a more efficient way even just to get the first name, let alone the second or the rest of the list. How do I go about this?

Comment: can you add some current output and expacted output?

Comment: Does your string include special "end-of-line" characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split your content in lines, then for each one split on dash, and keep first part

```
def partiesExtractor(doc):
    executives = []
    for line in doc.splitlines()[1:]:
        executives.append(line.split("-")[0].strip())
    return executives
    # return [line.split("-")[0].strip() for line in doc.splitlines()[1:]] # list-comprenhension


text = """Executives
Garet Hayes - Director, Public Relations
Ronald Allen - Chief Executive Officer
Gilbert Danielson - Executive Vice President and Chief Financial Officer
Steven Michaels - President
John Robinson - Executive Vice President and President and Chief Executive 
Officer, Progressive Finance Holdings LLC"""

print(partiesExtractor(text))  # ['Garet Hayes', 'Ronald Allen', 'Gilbert Danielson', 'Steven Michaels', 'John Robinson']
```

You can use a `regex` too

```
def partiesExtractor(doc):
    return re.findall("^[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+", doc, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar solution as @azro using a list comprehension:

```
def partiesExtractor(doc):
  return [line.split(" - ")[0] for line in doc.split("\n")[1:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

using regex:

```py
import re

s = '''Executives
Garet Hayes - Director, Public Relations
Ronald Allen - Chief Executive Officer
Gilbert Danielson - Executive Vice President and Chief Financial Officer
Steven Michaels - President
John Robinson - Executive Vice President and President and Chief Executive Officer, Progressive Finance Holdings LLC'''

reg = '(\w+\s\w+)\s-\s'

names = re.findall(reg,s)
print(names)
```

```
['Garet Hayes', 'Ronald Allen', 'Gilbert Danielson', 'Steven Michaels', 'John Robinson']
```